# Search specific position of file

Tags: c++, xml, io

i'm working on a xmlReader,so i want to Read between to tags in xml file but i don't know how to read a specific position in file? any suggestion?
what i do so far is this:

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class XmlReader
{
public:
    void Read(ifstream &Read, string searchWord,int args)
    {
        string line = "";
        string endline = "";
        string OptionLine = "";
        char array[100];
        bool isXml=false;
        while (!Read.eof())
        {
            string firstSearchWord = "<" + searchWord + ">";
            string endSearchWord = "</" + searchWord + ">";
            cout << line;
            if (line.find(firstSearchWord) && line.find(endSearchWord))
            {

            }
        }

    }
};
```

this just fine tags and correct syntax,i don't know how to read between them.
the example i want to read from is this: `<Gun1>Speed=100,Power=20,Ammo=50</Gun1>`

thanks..!

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just use your local storage?  Just read lines in sequence; start your specific tag capture when you see the start of it, and pause and redirect to another function when you see the end of it...  A string indexing function should be able to search for a specific tag directly, or a regexp could be used if more complexity is needed.

Comment: The above is not an `xml` reader: comments, raw blocks and the like must be handled.  Why not use an already available one?

Answer (score 2):

Searching through xml be treating it as a regular string isn't a good idea. The xml may contain commented out xml that you wouldn't ignore, or there may be `CDATA` section that you'd examine.

Your best bet is to use a proper xml parser to process the xml [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) is a great candidate for this sort of thing.